# JSP - TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl) returning null?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xslt

The java API guarantees that it will never return a null - but for me, it is!

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source)

Relevant code:

```
xml = new StreamSource(new URL(mondialURL).openStream());
xsl = new StreamSource(new File("/REMOVED/countriesnofilter.xsl"));
result = new StreamResult(new PrintWriter(out));

transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.transform(xml, result);
```

Since xml, xsl and result were made something using new, they -must- contain not null, so it must be transformer that's becoming null. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Throws this:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /dca/ass2/a.jsp:46

```
43:  result = new StreamResult(new PrintWriter(out));
44:  
45:  transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
46:  transformer.transform(xml, result);
47: 
48: %>
49:  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Get one country">


Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:451)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.dca.ass2.a_jsp._jspService(a_jsp.java:104)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
 org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

EDIT: It is DEFINITELY the case that the transformer is null somehow. Watch:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /dca/ass2/a.jsp:49

```
46:     
47:     xml.getInputStream();
48:     xsl.getInputStream();
49:     transformer.reset();
50:     
51:     //transformer.transform(xml, result);
52:
```

And it's a null pointer exception again. If it was because xml was null then it would have thrown an NPE at 47.

EDIT2: If I change newTransformer(xsl) to newTransformer() it works, so it's a problem in newTransformer(xsl).

Comment: Why are you sure that the npe caused by this `46:  transformer.transform(xml, result);` line? Do the line numbers in the stacktrace match the line numbers from the listing you provided?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /dca/ass2/a.jsp:46. 46:  transformer.transform(xml, result);. So the NPE is being caused by that line.

Comment: i am having same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470263/android-xsl-transformation-null-pointer-but-working-on-desktop . Did you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem, when some of my tests went wrong, after having added a new dependency to the project. Wondering how could this return **null** when its API says it's impossible, I revised it again:

> *"Obtain a new instance of a TransformerFactory. This static method creates a new factory instance This method uses the following ordered
>   lookup procedure to determine the TransformerFactory implementation
>   class to load: Use the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory system
>   property. ... [lookup order] ... Once an application has obtained a
>   reference to a TransformerFactory it can use the factory to configure
>   and obtain transformer instances."*

So, I had a look at **TransformerFactory API**, too, and it says:

> *"The system property that determines which Factory implementation to create is named "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory". This
>   property names a concrete subclass of the TransformerFactory abstract
>   class. If the property is not defined, a platform default is be
>   used."*

As I mentioned, the problem started when I added a new dependency to the project: another project that processes XML documents/signatures. I deleted the dependency, ran the test (that failed with the dependency added) and retrieved the specific class of the TransformerFactory. I added the dependency back and ran the test again: it was a different class now. So, as I supposed, the lookup procedure was instantiating a wrong TransformerFactory implementation, finding it in the added jar.

I didn't want to fix it adding another system property, so I changed the code like that:

```
private static final String TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_CLASS = "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl";

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_CLASS, null);
//null for default ClassLoader
```

and everything worked fine.

Comment: Your solution helped me to solve an issue where `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()` caused a `ClassNotFoundException`. I still have to understand why, since that exact line of code worked as a charm in the past.

Comment: @MaxArt I am glad that it was helpful. As the same solution worked for you, it is very likely that some dependency (a library that uses **TransformerFactory**, too, but a different implementation) was added to your project or, perhaps, you just updated an existing library to a newer version.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I guessed something like this but... Unfortunately I've totally lost track of what could have happened.

Comment: It seems that in the latest version of Java the `newInstance` method doesn't accept parameters anymore. You have to rely on the procedure reported [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28%29). I found that the simplest thing to do is using `System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_CLASS)`.

Comment: True, I didn't check it with the latest version of Java. Though having a look at the link in your comment, I can see that both `newInstance` methods are there (as in previous versions of Java): one without parameters and the other with the same parameters as in my answer :)

Comment: I think the documentation is still there just for those who still have to update their JRE. To my surprise, when I updated the other method was gone. Anyway, my comment was just to make things up to date, as there are faster ways to serialize XML documents and nodes (namely, `LSSerializer`s and Apache utilities(.

Comment: You are right about better ways to serialize XML, I totally agree and appreciate your comment. I think that this issue will mostly arise (as it did in my case) when working with legacy code and/or 3-rd party code that you cannot refactor.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4852168/366493?stw=1&ref%20=twitbtn&text=TransformerFactory.newInstance%28%29.newTransformer%28streamSource%29%20returns%20null)'s answer seems to indicate this will happen when the XSL is invalid, which would explain what I'm currently running into.

In our specific case, an XML editor that was used silently inserted an invisible character in the first position of the file.  Printing the first few bytes of the file showed this.  Using a more powerful editor, we removed the offending bytes from the file and all was well.

Comment: for me it was after a svn update, I didn't saw there was a conflict in the xsl, making the xsl in invalid xml

Answer (score 0):

The input stream is empty.

Comment: I can confirm this is not the case: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /dca/ass2/a.jsp:49

46:  
47:  xml.getInputStream();
48:  xsl.getInputStream();
49:  transformer.reset();
50:  
51:  //transformer.transform(xml, result);
52: So it throws an exception because transformer is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether xml is null/empty before passing it it.  I think you'll find it's empty.

e.g. is `new StreamSource(new URL(mondialURL).openStream())` returning null or and empty object?