# TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(streamSource) returns null

Tags: java, groovy, xslt, xalan

How could that be that TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(streamSource) returns null. According to javadoc this is not possible:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer(javax.xml.transform.Source)

here's groovy code sample

```
    def is = new ClassPathResource('xslt/MySpace-Contact.xsl').inputStream
    println is
    def streamSource = new StreamSource(is)
    println streamSource
    def factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    println factory
    def tr = factory.newTransformer(streamSource)
    println tr
```

Here's the output:

`--Output from testTransformation--

java.io.BufferedInputStream@32999f10

javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource@399ed64

org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl@6eb04214

null`

Comment: you are printing `factory` 2 times

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here and I doubt anyone else does either. Please try and formulate your problem as a question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question. If XSLT file is not valid, that will happen (newTransformer(Source) will return `null`). I think that should be reported to Oracle so they change the javadoc. It's still POSSIBLE that `null` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains a typo. The last statement prints "tf" rather than "tr". "tf" is an uninitialized script variable, hence its value is null.

Comment: thanks ;) I was changed it directly here, that's typo indeed.