# Write Document to Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, dom, persistence, arrays

I've used Java DOM to edit an XML template and now want to store the resulting `Document` in the android private internal storage, as per the [official API guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

So far I have:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = dBuilder.parse(ThisApplication.resources().openRawResource(R.raw.default_store));

// Populate document here.

//Convert document to byte[]
Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(source, result); /// transformer is null!!!!!!!

// Store byte[] in internal storage
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data_store", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(out.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

At the moment, I am getting a null pointer exception trying to call `tranform()` on `transformer`. The `TransformerFactory` [API says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer%28%29) that `newTransformer();` can never return null, but apparently it's also [platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096295/jsp-transformerfactory-newinstance-newtransformerxsl-returning-null) and in my case ***is*** returning null.

So, the question is how else can I either;

**A)** convert a `Document` object into a `byte[]` or

**B)** find another way to save a document to internal storage?

*Edit: [Android bug report filed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66421).*

Comment: I have submitted an Android bug report, but in the meantime any work arounds or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JDOM Document is Serializable, you can just write a [Serializable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array)

I would do it something like:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
out.writeObject(document);
out.close();
```

Comment: When trying this I am just getting a `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: Maybe you're using org.w3c.dom.Document? I see you're using [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html)? JDOM [Document](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Document.html) is indeed Serializable.

Comment: Doing a bit search people point that they get errors in the transformer when the source is not valid. I see you initialize the source as new DOMSource(node) instead of new DOMSource(doc)? But it's weird because the Documentation says that "factory.newTransformer()" never returns null.

Comment: Yep, your quite right I have been using Java 'DOM', not 'JDOM'. Accidental acronym there. `node` is a variable left over from the method I took the code from (all the code above isn't in the same place). I will change the code above to compensate.

Comment: +1 - I can fall back on this if I need to, but it currently means I will have to rewrite a lot of my code that populates the XML. So I am still looking for a solution that doesn't use external libraries.

Comment: @RudiKershaw - you initially tagged this as JDOM (not complaining) but since I am the maintainder of JDOM (and I got an e-mail) I thought I would tell you that you **can** do XSLT with JDOM on android. Also, there are other issues with XML on android. FYI, read this [JDOM / Android support page](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-and-Android)

Comment: @rolfl - JDOM is starting to look more and more appealing, and it looks like I might have to fall back on using it and just rewrite a few of my classes. But I want to leave the question open a little while in case anyone has any solutions that don't require external libraries.